# Writing selected mail received time to a sharepoint list using office JS

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am newbie and apologize for any rule breaking here. I am seeking support for writing data of an email and its headers to a SharePoint list using office js. I am using **script lab** for coding which is an addin to my outlook.

Thanking you in advance and apologies once again if something written not inline to the rules.

Answer (score 0):

`OfficeJS` doesn't provide anything for writing data to a SharePoint list. But it can be used for retrieving the data from an Outlook item, for example:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.getAllInternetHeadersAsync(getCallback);

function getCallback(asyncResult) {
  if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
    console.log("Sender's preferred fruit: " + asyncResult.value.match(/x-preferred-fruit:.*/gim)[0].slice(19));
    console.log("Sender's preferred vegetable: " + asyncResult.value.match(/x-preferred-vegetable:.*/gim)[0].slice(23));
  } else {
    console.log("Error getting preferences from header: " + JSON.stringify(asyncResult.error));
  }
}
```

Read more about how to set, get, and remove custom headers in the [Get and set internet headers on a message in an Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/internet-headers) article.

Also you may find the [Get and set Outlook item data in read or compose forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/item-data) page helpful.

Comment: You can write to a SharePoint list using [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/graph).

Comment: I tried Microsoft Graph but it didn't worked probably i am new to this as well. Do you have some sample code for my reference.

Comment: See [Working with SharePoint sites in Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sharepoint?view=graph-rest-1.0).